# Geometric intuition behind Jacobi Identity

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-derivative

I'm currently trying to understand the Lie bracket of smooth vector fields.The bracket operation satisfies the Jacobian Identity: If X and Y are two smooth vector fields on a manifold, we define their Lie bracket as $[X,Y]=XY-YX.$ Using that definition, we have $[X,[Y,Z]]+[Y,[Z,X]]+[Z,[X,Y]]=0. $ I am familiar with the Lie derivative and I know the bracket operation coincides with the Lie derivative. I'm wondering if there is a geometric intuition behind this identity.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/423730/what-is-the-interpretation-of-jacobi-identity-on-sympletic-manifold

Comment: This isn't as geometric as you'd like, but it says $L_X$ acts as a derivation: $L_X[Y,Z] = [L_X Y,Z] + [Y,L_X Z]$.

Comment: It's a bit of a diversion, but in Lie groups you can think of the Jacobi identity as the infinitesimal version of the associative law $(ab)c=a(bc)$. This in turn applies to vector fields since they generate the (associative) diffeomorphism group of the manifold.